# KQL - Calculating percentage with summarized value

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I would like to calculate the percentage based on already summarized value and with one another condition
So, example below

```
|summarize Count1= dcount(ShipmentId) by Geography, Initial_replan
```

With this Query I will get the result somethin like this

| Geography | Initial replan | Count1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Europe | Initial | 120009 |
| Asia | Replan | 240000 |
| Asia | Initial | 350000 |

but based on count1 value I would like to calculate the percentage
so like

```
Table1 
|summarize Count1= dcount(ShipmentId) by Geography, Initial_replan
|summarize Initial_percentage = iff(Initial_replan == Initial, Count1 / sum(Count1), toreal(0))
```

so that I can get percentage of initial and for the replan got 0 and I calculate another one for replan with same condition

If I run this code I got the error Initial_replan is already in the summarize so I cannot operate this query
Can you help to make this out?

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide the required results as a table.

Answer (score 0):

I have used extend operator for a new column and added round function to calculate percentage per column.

Here is sample query to calculate Percentage.

```
let Table1 = datatable(ShipmentId:string, Geography:string, Initial_replan:string, Count:int)
[ '01','Europe', 'Initial', 120009,
'02','Asia', 'Replan', 240000,
'03', 'Asia', 'Initial', 350000,];
Table1    
| summarize Count1 = sum(Count) by Geography, Initial_replan
| extend Percentage = round(Count1 * 100 / toscalar(Table1
| summarize sum(Count)),2)
```

Here is the result
[image]

Here is the [link](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA12QQWvDMAyF7/kVujkZhjnpdljLDqWM0dtoeytjKI1IDY4THAXWsR9fJU0TNnyR5O89%20dkRwwFzRym8QoEsR5p4f7ZNRZ63xbLlYH2p4Z3qMmBzvkyTrbds0X0Fahz6abypO89L6zmJjgCgTKq0eutC3ZDSoEaVlGlmjHnREMGAZYKtW4s9tBsspcqehDETs%20gv79DstHgeqM9VNGaJfqHtqgqD/aHbg/p8MoqHJoH8Mgf6n0TE9M3kC/igcJJfwJJEHURZxKPZA6TGwCNw3Z7QYYhvi//sndclOkuuYwULsmoBAAA=) for above sample query